# opensource network monitoring tools developed in java

Tags: java, snmp, opennms

i want to know the best opensource network monitoring tool developed in java with very good support via forums and which should have the following features ..

- Fault and Alert mgmt
- Performance Poll graphs
- inventory mgmt
- config management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try JNM [JNM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnm/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Hyperic. http://www.hyperic.com/   Sounds like it will fit all your requirements and you can get commercial support should you need or want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenNMS  http://www.opennms.org  I have been supported by the community very well.  Best avenue is IRC.